# SAP netweaver 7.0 portal- seeing junk page when we access /nwa ,/sld

Tags: netweaver, sld, sap-enterprise-portal

We We are using Sap Netweaver portal 7.02.I am new to this SAP portal.

All of sudden we started seeing junk page when we access /nwa, /sld. When we try to access /index.html it shows links to Web Dynpro Tools,SAP NetWeaver Administrator etc.

Once we click any of these links it shows same junk page after login screen. When we try to access actual portal, we don't see any of the menu items.

Please help us solving this issue.

This is the junk characters i get in the browser.

```
��]ks�F������P�k����x<��)vL�/���$U[E5R I��2fS�o���3vfg6k@R�9}�\�>���7�������}�B�j�f���⧽z��h7ԍ�B���;����`�X<�Ν~������o޴C�4� �`NL����[tM�'� -�3�F��8C�0B�Yx���|���|h#Ӣ'9�SY��`>z?$��^��۷Oru�������#9d�_'9N�xQTt���������a.�kls׵��ƪqܜ� �p���4�tf-�b�b���E��~���8���f�3~�����sׁ��������c�� r�5@v�;�Gl�䦷�s,+-����b*�Q�$W(� kקaE�������kd�eZ���ط�.�)pU�̊�;ĖC�����Oo��K��-ÿ�^�p��;�qr#���#�n焈��Υ5�����
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the webdynpro libraries are corrupted. Deploy the webdynpro framework libraries again.

Comment: After restoring to previous stage,it worked for couple of hours.After that again it showing up the same error.